# Change fields shown based on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form.html.erb that includes this:

```
<%= nested_form_for(@store) do |f| %>

  <%= select_tag :type, options_for_select(['Book' , 'Magazine' , 'Video'])%>

  <%= f.fields_for :product_fields do |builder| %>
    <%= builder.text_field :type %>
    <%= builder.text_area :content %>
    <%= builder.text_field :type %>
    <%= builder.text_area :content%>
    <%= builder.text_field :type %>
    <%= builder.text_area :content %>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

What I want to do is, based on what you selected in the select dropdown, change the text fields you get, while still keeping the rails associations. So, for example, if you selected "Book", you might get:

```
<%= builder.text_field :type %>
<%= builder.text_area :content %>
```

but if you select "Magazine", you might get:

```
<%= builder.text_field :type %>
<%= builder.text_area :content %>
<%= builder.text_field :type %>
<%= builder.text_area :content %>
<%= builder.text_field :type %>
<%= builder.text_area :content %>
<%= builder.text_field :type %>
<%= builder.text_area :content %>
```

I know I can do this by just doing calling jQuery hide() and then showing them on select change, but is there a cleaner/better way?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: You could use jQuery to solve this.